# Error running MiKTex in Ubuntu 22

Tags: 22.04, latex

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my system. I installed the 'texlive-full' for MiKTeX. I even installed TeXMaker and added the path in there /home/usr/bin. But I still get this error message when I run any .tex file.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I resolve this issue?